# Merge multiple excel tables into one

Tags: excel, csv

I have 3000 tables like these ones in the same excel sheet:

[txt sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVYkC.jpg)

I need to merge all this tables into 1, i'm making =VLOOKUP(CSV!$B$2,TXT!$A:$B,2,FALSE) under Last Name: and draging down, but i always get the 1st user data, as you can see under:

[csv sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGam1.jpg)

How can i get the user info in each row from these tables? Is VLOOKUP viable for this case?

PS: I only need the info assigned in csv sheet

Comment: You will need to use a INDEX formula with LARGE(IF()) or AGGREGATE() to return the correct Row number.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the quick reply, now i did insert: =INDEX(B1:B200,MATCH(LARGE(IF(A1:A200=Last Name:,B1:200,""),1),B1:B200,0)) but i still get errors

Comment: I am feeling lazy at the moment and will not retype your information.  If you post the data as text in the original post I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Formula in `E3` cell

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$5009,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$5009=E$2,ROW($C$2:$C$5009)-MIN(ROW($C$2:$C$5009))+1),ROWS($E$2:E2))),"")
```

After click `F2` and press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`

[image]